# page Action in pardot not working

Tags: salesforcedx, automationstudio, analytics, pardot, tracking

Please help me
I created a page action in pardot so that i can track that page view but it is not working

"https://netrocon.com/how-to-get-the-most-out-of-pardot-page-actions/" is the link that i want to track. Also i am attaching screenshot of "Page action"

`<form action="http://go.pardot.com/l/860113/2020-04-12/3rbz" method="post"><input` type="text" name="email" lable="Email">
`<input type="submit" >`
`<a href="https://netrocon.com/how-to-get-the-most-out-of-pardot-page-actions/" >here</a><script type="text/javascript">`
piAId = '*****';
piCId = '****';
piHostname = 'pi.pardot.com';

(function() {
    function async_load(){
        var s = document.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript';
        s.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://pi' : 'http://cdn') + '.pardot.com/pd.js';
        var c = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; c.parentNode.insertBefore(s, c);
    }
    if(window.attachEvent) { window.attachEvent('onload', async_load); }
    else { window.addEventListener('load', async_load, false); }
})();
`</script>
</form>`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the URL you posted, it doesn't appear that the Pardot Tracking code is on the page. This tracking code needs to be there so that Pardot knows a page view happened.

Comment: Thank you for reply
so you saying if i create a record with this URL "https://netrocon.com/how-to-get-the-most-out-of-pardot-page-actions/"

Then on this particular page tracking code should be present.. is that correct?

Comment: You need to place the tracking code that Pardot gives you into the HTML on the page. Similar to adding any other analytics tracking code to a page. You shouldn't need to create anything else in Pardot.